# Sizing issue with iFrame on mobile (iOS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, shopify

I made a custom `Shopify` cart carousel and it's [hosted on my Shopify here](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0246/7086/3424/files/index.html?8580882792227341575) and working on its own perfectly. I tried to embed it as an iFrame on my site (see code below) but the width is not working properly on my site or even as I load it locally on iOS (I haven't tried it on Android but I assume it's the same on all mobile). I want it to size the width correctly on mobile. It works fine on my computer but not on mobile for some inexplicable reason. Can you please help me fix this issue?

```html
<style>
  .centerAlign {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<center>
<iframe id="sim" frameBorder="0" class="centerAlign" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0246/7086/3424/files/index.html?8154775124260488467" width="800" height="1000" onload="updateSize()">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</center>

<script>

function updateSize() {
    var size = {
      width: window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight
  }
    
  if (size.width <= 800) {
   document.getElementById("sim").width = size.width;
   document.getElementById("sim").height = (size.width) * 1.5;
  }
  else {
     document.getElementById("sim").width = 800;
    document.getElementById("sim").height = 800 * 1.5;
  }
}

updateSize();

window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
    updateSize();
})

</script>
```